# google-apps-script Format Date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, format

I am beginner in script programing and I would like to format the date from today as following ("DD-MM-YY).
I have written the following script

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Déclaration des variables
var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var DerniereLigne =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var DateToday = new Date();
var YearToday = DateToday.getYear();
var DayToday = DateToday.getDate();
var MonthToday = DateToday.getMonth() + 1;
var ID = String(DayToday) + String(MonthToday) + String(YearToday);

//Création de l'ID dans la derniére ligne et colonne "N"
SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,14).setValue(ID);
}
```

and the results is obviously for today (August 21, 2015) is "21082015", but I want only "210815".

Could somebody help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternative 1:** string manipulation

Try to replace with this:

```
var YearToday = DateToday.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
```

`getFullYear()` is guaranteed to return a four digit year, so you can then use string manipulation to get the two last characters from that.

**Alternative 2:** `Utilities.formatDate`

Look into the function [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format). It can save you a lot of code.

You can delete most of your line and just write:

```
var ID = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'ddMMYY');
```

or

```
var ID = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'dd-MM-YY');
```

if you wanted those hyphens.

Comment: Thank you so much. The new script is more simple and functional.